# Enable session_state parameter in authentication response - Keycloak 18.0.0

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, quarkus

The `session_state` parameter which used to be present in the authentication/ token response is not present in keycloak version 18.0.0 along with the `refresh_token`. Although there is an option under Clients -> OpenID Connect Compatibility Modes to exclude/include this, that doesn't seem to do anything.

We're using this value in our application hence with the upgrade to keycloak 18.0.0 the authentication flow seem to be broken.

Is there any way we can include this parameter in the authentication response?

[image]

Comment: Share your client configuration here

Comment: added to the original post @abhijeet